# Calling a click event handler on run-time HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I have an HTML file, in which I am creating a text area when user clicks inside a table cell. Basically, it is a datagrid created using table, and when user clicks on one, it removes the text in cell and replace it with a text area. Below is the code I am using in table's onClick handler.

```
summaryTableElement.innerHTML = "<textarea id='summaryTextBox' value='TestString' onclick='doNothing(this.id)'> </textarea> <input type='button' onclick='saveSummary()' value='Save' /> "
```

This is all working fine, and it creates a text area perfectly. It bugs out when user clicks on the text area to modify the data. In that case, the click event handler of the text area never fires. Instead, the table receives the click event, resulting in creating another text area. No matter what user does, the text area receives no event at all.

Now, I am confused as to what to do here.

Edit:

I checked again. turns out, it is firing the child's click event handler. But, event is propagating to parent element too.

Edit:

I tried adding following condition in parent's click event handler

```
if (id.toString() == "SummaryData")
```

but this returns true even for child element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag indicating the click once. If it is clicked already, then don't run the function. Now the problem of the text area. in your dynamically getting created html code, add an `onfocus` event handler insteaad of onclick. Also the 'id's cannot be the same for all the text areas you are adding dynamically. Use something like `"id='xyz"+i+"'"` where 'i' represents a count which is the number of the text area getting added.

Comment: Thanks. I will try out using random id. Although, if I don't handle click event on text area, it still passes through to the parent. So, onfocus won't be any help. 

I will try using a flag instead. If that works, awesome.

Comment: Good. But I think instead of random Id, a global count will probably work better

Comment: I think so too. Although, that id doesn't matter. I save the data to a global string as soon as user finish entering the text, so id is not needed. Added it just for safety purposes.